# How to cancel tcl http request

Tags: http, tcl

```
http::geturl "http://xxxx:8080/api/security/oauth2/token" \
        -headers {} -method POST -type application/x-www-form-urlencoded \
        -query username=admin&grant_type=password&password=admin&client_id=security-service
```

I have the above `tcl http request`.

Please suggest how can i cancel this `request` if `response time` is large?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself.*

Looking at the [http documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm), I think you should specify a `-timeout flag` in your intitial `http::geturl` call to prevent your application from hanging forever if something strange happens.

Answering your original question, it seems that to cancel the request you should call `http::reset` passing the token returned by your original `http::geturl` call. Of course, that won't actually be returned to you until the request completes *unless* you also specify `-command`, in which case the token will be passed to the script you specify.